# How to actually use rails-settings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use [rails-settings](https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings) gem but i'm not sure how to do that.

I've added `ledermann-rails-gem` gem to Gemfile, runned `bundle install`, generated a migration based on what's written in wiki, runned `rake db:migrate`, restarted a server and now, when i'm trying to do anything from rails-settings wiki, i'm getting an error.

Let's say i want to create new variable so i'm putting this code to my controller:

```
Settings.foo = "bar"
```

It gives me the following error:

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Settings
```

I'm quite 'fresh' in rails development and probably there is some small thing which wasn't mentioned in the wiki because it's obvious (but not for me!). Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @LyubenTodorov he said he did in the question... did you read it?